# Splitting String using Multiple Entries from a List

Tags: scala

I have following list of splitters:

```
    val splitd = list(" or ", " and ", " up to ")
```

and the following string:

```
    val st = "You should eat 2 kg apples a week or 2 bananas everyday; up to a month you should eat 5g of ginger everyday"
```

I want following output:

```
    val entry = List("You should eat 2 kg apples a week", "2 bananas everyday;", "a month you should eat 5g of ginger everyday")
```

If there is no entry in "splitd" matching the content in "st" then full string "st" should be returned. Thanks in advance for your help.

Dear @Shadowlands and @marstran, need your help again.

Comment: @jwvh No, leaving "or" was a typo. Any help now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
splitd.foldLeft(List(st)) {
  case (acc, spl) => acc.flatMap(item => item.split(spl).toList)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly fine. Can you please suggest any online reference where I can get a deeper understanding of Map, folding etc. etc. SCALA cookbook, I am referring to, has very simple examples.

Comment: I would recommend 'Functional Programming in Scala' by Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason.